# Retrieving data to show in amcharts

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, amcharts

I'm trying to show data in a chart, this time, using amchart and angular to consume REST Service.

this is the code to consume service and call amchart:

```
function GetData($scope, $http){
$http.get('http://localhost/api/v1/index.php/data').
    success(function(data){
    //$scope.dados = data;

            var json = data; 

        var chart = AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv", {
          "type": "serial",
          "theme": "light",
          "dataProvider": data,
          "valueAxes": [ {
            "gridColor": "#FFFFFF",
            "gridAlpha": 0.2,
            "dashLength": 0
          } ],
          "gridAboveGraphs": true,
          "startDuration": 1,
          "graphs": [ {
            "balloonText": "[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b>",
            "fillAlphas": 0.8,
            "lineAlpha": 0.2,
            "type": "column",
            "valueField": "visits"
          } ],
          "chartCursor": {
            "categoryBalloonEnabled": false,
            "cursorAlpha": 0,
            "zoomable": false
          },
          "categoryField": "country",
          "categoryAxis": {
            "gridPosition": "start",
            "gridAlpha": 0,
            "tickPosition": "start",
            "tickLength": 20
          },
          "export": {
            "enabled": true
          }

        } );          

});
```

}

this is my html

```
<body ng-controller="GetData">
    <div id="chartdiv" style="width: 100%; height: 500px"></div>
</body>
```

It is not showing anything

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a completely blank output in your browser? if so check for javascript errors in your browser. this should point you in the right direction.
are you including the amcharts libraries somewhere? I cannot see this in your html or js.

if you are seeing a blank chart, then it is likely that there is a problem with your json, check or post here for help with that.

Comment: please leave suggestion as comments

Comment: it is showing undefined in the browser... no javascript errors... yes, i'm including the amcharts libraries... it is the same json i am using in chart.js and here is working... the var "data" is the json

Comment: normally, if it shows as undefined in the browser, then there is a mismatch between the names that you are specifying in the amcharts (ie "visits" and "country") and the json object itself, check for capital letters? or post your "data" object here.